# How does one normalize this wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, normalization

Here is the question:

[image]

So I could write $ N = \dfrac{1}{{\sqrt{<Ψ|Ψ>}}} $, right?
Considering the parentheses in the exponential term, it looks like a good idea to switch to spherical polar coordinates. So I used $ x = r sin(θ)cos(φ)$ ; $ y = r sin(θ)sin(φ) $ ; $ z = r cos(θ) $ to rewrite Ψ (without the N, because I'll use the equation above eventually) $$ Ψ(x,y,z) = \sqrt{r sin(θ)cos(φ)r sin(θ)sin(φ)r cos(θ)} * e^{-ar^2} $$$$Ψ(x,y,z) = \sqrt{r^3 sin^2(θ)cos(θ)cos(φ) sin(φ)} * e^{-ar^2} $$$$Ψ(x,y,z) = r^{3/2} sin(θ)[cos(θ)]^{1/2}[cos(φ)]^{1/2} [sin(φ)]^{1/2} * e^{-ar^2} $$

So then, because there are no imaginary terms in the wavefunction,

$$ <Ψ|Ψ> = \int_{0}^{∞} dr \int_{0}^{2π} dθ \int_{0}^{π} dφ [ r^3 sin^2(θ)cos(θ)cos(φ)sin(φ) * e^{-2ar^2}]$$

I don't know if what I've done so far makes sense, or where to go from there. I get the feeling there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: The integral is actually pretty straightforward in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: There is an easier way. Note that the integrand splits into a product of functions $f(x)g(y)h(z)$. The integral over $x,y$ and $z$ turn out to be identical. Therefore you need to calculate the value of $$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\; x e^{-2ax^2}.$$

Comment: Note that your last expression for the integral in spherical coordinates is wrong, due to missing factors in the integration measure.

Comment: @Chylomicron The best way is what Mark Mitchison said, if you just notice that $xdx$ is the derivative of a more useful variable than $x$.

Comment: OKay, thank you! I get $\dfrac{1}{4} e^{-8}$ for one of the integrals, so then because there are three of them I figure it makes sense to cube it. Then with $N^2(\dfrac{1}{64}e^{-24})=1$, I do a little more algebra and land at $N = 8e^{12}$. Is that right? Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: I'm not going to check your answer. You understand the concept. Our work is done here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I could write $ N = \dfrac{1}{{\sqrt{<Ψ|Ψ>}}} $, right?

Well, no, not exactly, since you have included "N" in your definition of Psi. But I think that what *you think you mean* is correct. What you mean to say is that if
$$
\Psi(x,y,z)=Nf(x,y,z)
$$
then
$$
N=\frac{1}{\sqrt{<f|f>}}
$$
not
$$
N=\frac{1}{\sqrt{<\Psi|\Psi>}}\;.
$$

In which case what you are doing is correct:
$$
\int \Psi^2 \equiv 1 = N^2\int d^3r x y z e^{-2a(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\;.
$$
so
$$
N=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\int d^3r x y z e^{-2a(x^2+y^2+z^2)}}}
$$